# How to call class method by java annotation name with Jackson?

Tags: java, javabeans, fasterxml

Wondering if there is a way to call the getter methods by the Jackson annotation property name (eg. `"value"`) instead of the method name (eg. `getName()`) or point me to the right direction?

```
public class Person {

    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("value")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("value")
    public void setSet(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

My goal is to call multiple methods by iterating trough a list of java annotation property names.

Comment: You can check for the annotations and their parameters on a method through the Reflection API, and you can also call the appropriate method through that API.

Comment: This is doable. You can put the same annotation on your variable and remove it from setter and getter. This will work for sure.

Comment: Although it's not your stated goal, if all you want is the value of the property then it might be simpler to just convert the object to a Map and get the values from the map. `Map<String,Object> map = objectMapper.convertValue(person, new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>(){});` And then: `String s = (String) map.get("value");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used as an answer by Allen D.

```
 Map<String,Object> map = new ObjectMapper.convertValue(person, new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>(){});
 String s = (String) map.get("value");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to identify and call the methods directly you could use reflection.  Something like (with no exception management):

```java
        SomeObject object = ...;                                                
        Class<?> type = object.getClass();                                      
                                                                                
        for (Method method : type.getMethods()) {                               
            JsonProperty property = method.getAnnotation(JsonProperty.class);   
                                                                                
            if (property != null && property.value().equals("value")) {         
                if (method.getParameterCount() == 0) {                          
                    Object value = method.invoke(object);                       
                    ...                                                         
                }                                                               
            }                                                                   
        }
```

Comment: Im getting nulls when getting the annotations for the class (`getAnnotation`). FYI Im referencing my `Person` class with all the data and not the class (Person.class)

Comment: JsonProperty.value() must not be specified in your code.  You'd have to parse Method.getName() in that case.

Comment: I'd suggest using introspection to get PersonBeanInfo and then you reflection on the methods identified by Introspection.